# Is there any way to develop the website like this (https://slackdemo.com)?

Tags: animation, user-interaction

I saw the website with awesome animations (URL- https://slackdemo.com).
I want to create a website like this kind of animations and Interactions.

So anyone please help me, which kind of technology they used and how to achieve this?
I'm very curious to develop this kind of animation in my project. if you know any reference or idea about this please share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're using the GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP): https://greensock.com/get-started/

Comment: Yeah.. they used GSAP only. but the way of revealing animations and interactions are completely different. If you have any idea about that part?

Comment: Check out https://damp-lake-50659.herokuapp.com/ - there are good discussion groups there to delve into GSAP in more detail.

Comment: Thank u so much... I think it could be helpful.